# SSRS Invoice Header repeating

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS invoice report. When exporting to pdf it is repeating the top heading data on each page for an invoice data. When viewing in the report writer the invoice data is together. As I export to pdf invoice top data is repeating for the same invoice.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Shubh's suggestions are sound. If it's not working then edit your question and show the report design as you originally had it and as it is now and then what the output looks like and we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could look at the advanced setting for the group header and ensure repeat on new page is set to false..

To the right of Column Group.. click the little down arrow.. 
Select "Advanced Mode"..

Click on the **Row Group** Static header elements and set the `"RepeatOnNewPage"` property to False..

You have to set ALL of the static elements to False.. else report will error. A bit of trial and error will get you there.

Comment: The problem is when I'm exporting to pdf or printing the Customer, inv number inv date, and the middle invoice line are repeating in each page.

Comment: @nmcs I'm not entirely sure what you mean by this.. "middle invoice line".. is that part of the report header? Are you able to show with images what you mean??

Answer (score 0):

Move the header out of the grouping. I normally add a new row above out of the group, place a rectangle and then insert the header image or text. Another way would be to add a new tablix above your current tablix and just add the header in that tablix. Make sure both tablix are joined together otherwise space would show up when you extract as pdf or excel.

Comment: It makes my invoice completely mess.